# Custom Error Pages for particular controllers in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

If we call a method abc() within a controller named Example. Suppose abc() is not present in Example controller.

In such cases i need to display a custom error message instead of

---

**404 Page Not Found**

The page you requested was not found.

---

for this particular controller only.

I know we can set custom error pages, but it applies to all controller.
I need to use it with one controller only.

For Eg:

```
class Example extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        echo "index page";
    }

    function xyz() 
    {
        echo "xyz page";
    }
}
```

if i call **example/xyz** it displays output as '**xyz page**'

but if i call **example/abc**  it show page not found error. (i need custom message for this controller only).

Thank You...

Comment: Use remap if function doesn't exists then return your own error screen. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping Added sample code in Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar to below. If the method exists call it otherwise display your own error message.

```
function _remap( $method )
{
    // $method contains the second segment of your URI
    if(method_exists($this, $method ) )     
    {
         $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
         //your custom coding here
    }
}
```

Comment: i think  $this->$method(); is correct in if statement

Comment: another correction function exists not working: use method_exists instead - refer ci user guide